# Computers missing in "Select Users, Computers, or Groups" dialog

Tags: permissions, active-directory, users

I have four machines in a small Windows domain and am having a problem assigning permissions properly. When I go to add a local account to a folder for access, I am presented with the "Select Users, Computers, or Groups" dialog. By default, my domain is set in the location field. Clicking on the Locations button shows me only the Entire Directory/domain and one of my servers. The local machine is not shown at all, thus preventing me from assigning a local user group permissions.

Does anyone have any thoughts about this?

Comment: What OS is your server?  Is it an AD Domain? 2000/3/8?

Answer (score 2):

I've only seen that behavior on DC's - which don't have local users. If it's not a DC i would try a reboot and also fully qualifying the user name as `<LOCALMACHINE>\<user>`

Comment: +1 Yeah that's what I was trying to get at with my comments/questions.  I'd assume his problem is exactly as you said - I think he's saying it's his DC.

Comment: +1 from me too, sounds like nail on the head.